# In a litter of 5 puppies, what is the probability that 2 males and 3 females are not obtained, or that 2 females and 3 males are not obtained?

Tags: probability

I have this statement:

> In a litter of $5$ puppies, what is the probability that $2$ males and $3$ females are not obtained, or that $2$ females and $3$ males are not obtained?

My attempt was:

Make a Pascal's triangle to get the odds.

Let $M = Males, F = Females$

$1F^5M^0-5F^4M^1-10F^3M^2-10F^2M^3-5FM^4-1F^0M^5$

The probability of that $2$ males and $3$ females are **not** obtained is:

$1F^5M^0-5F^4M^1-\underbrace{10F^3M^2}_\text{Exclude this probability}-10F^2M^3-5FM^4-1F^0M^5$

$32/32 - 10/32 = 22/32$

Same procedure with the probability of that $2$ females and $3$ males are **not** obtained, that is $22/32$

Now i need the intersection that is $1F^5M^0 + 5F^4M^1 +5FM^4+1F^0M^5=12/32$ cases.

So, the probability is $22/32 + 22/32 - 12/32 = 32/32$. But this is wrong.

What is wrong with my development? I want to know where is my error and how to get an answer according my development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One slight error that it might be: $22/32 + 22/32 - 12/32 = (22 + 22 - 12)/32 = 32/32 = 1$. Not sure if this is the proper answer, just something I noticed.

Comment: Probability $2$ males and $3$ females are obtained is $10/32$; probability $3$ males and $2$ females are obtained is also $10/32;$ probability neither of those is $1-2\times10/32=1-20/32=12/32=3/8$

Comment: I understrand that Tanner, but what is wrong in my development?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look strictly at Pascal's triangle, notice that the row adds up to $2^5=32$.  The numbers that you want to exclude are $10$ and $10$.  Therefore, you have
$$1-\frac{10+10}{32}=1-\frac{20}{32}=\frac{12}{32}=\frac38.$$

You have already counted females as non-males, and therefore, do not need to consider one case for males as the counter, then another case for females as the counter.  That is, you only need to consider that in $$\binom{5}{r}=\frac{5!}{r!\ (5-r)!}$$
for every $r$ males, you have $5-r$ females.

Comment: I have a little doubt, You are excluding two probabilides at the same time, that is: $P(A) = 10/32, P(B) = 10/32$ That is: ''$A$ and $B$ does NOT happen'', but that is intersection and not union as the question asks, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: What is the probability of you getting a set of $2M3F$ AND $3M2F$ at the same time?  In general, remember that disjoint sets have an intersection of $0$.

Comment: I know that the intersection is $0$. But that generates my doubt, means that if $P(A \cap B) = 0$,. i.e ''Probability that A and B does not happen' then $P(A \cap B)^c = 1$ but $1 \neq 3/8$, what am i misunderstanding?

Comment: The complement is there is a probability of $1$ that you will not get $A$ and $B$; it doesn't say anything about the other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your help.If it's not too much to ask, Can you provide a development using directly the complement as my development? I still without understand why my development is bad.

Comment: If $A$ is the event (NOT $2M3F$) and $B$ is the event (NOT $3M2F$), then to calculate $P(A\cup B)$ using the complement, we can take 

\begin{align}
1-(P(\textrm{NOT } A)+P(\textrm{NOT } B))&=1-(P(\textrm{NOT NOT } 2M3F)+P(\textrm{NOT NOT } 3M2F))\\
&=1-\bigg(\frac{10}{32}+\frac{10}{32}\bigg)\\
&=\frac38
\end{align}

which as you'll see is exactly what I provided as my solution.

Comment: I mean using directly the prob of $NOT A$ instead of $NOT NOT A$

Comment: What exactly is your event $A$?

Comment: I mean to A = NOT 2M3F

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the number of female puppies.  When you calculated $\Pr(F \neq 3)$, you found 
$$\Pr(F \neq 3) = \Pr(F = 0) + \Pr(F = 1) + \Pr(F = 2) + \Pr(F = 4) + \Pr(F = 5)$$
When you calculated $\Pr(F \neq 2)$, you found
$$\Pr(F \neq 2) = \Pr(F = 0) + \Pr(F = 1) + \Pr(F = 3) + \Pr(F = 4) + \Pr(F = 5)$$
When you calculated $\Pr(F \neq 2 \cap F \neq 3)$, you calculated
$$\Pr(F \neq 2 \cap F \neq 3) = \Pr(F = 0) + \Pr(F = 1) + \Pr(F = 4) + \Pr(F = 5)$$
Hence, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(F \neq 2) & + \Pr(F \neq 3) - \Pr(F \neq 2 \cap F \neq 3)\\ & \quad = \Pr(F = 0) + \Pr(F = 1) + \Pr(F = 2) + \Pr(F = 3) + \Pr(F = 4) + \Pr(F = 5)\\
& \qquad = 1
\end{align*}
What you want to calculate is simply $\Pr(F \neq 2 \cap F \neq 3)$.

Comment: But that is intersecion and not union as the statement asks

Comment: To get a correct answer, that intersection must be 1, but i dont know where does that 1 come from

Comment: Or in this case the intersection is equal to the union?

Comment: According to Morgan'  Laws, i want to get $P( A^c \cup B^c)$ where $A,B$ are mutually excluyent. Thus, $P( A^c \cup B^c) =  P( A \cap B)^c $,but $P(A \cap B) = 0$, then the complement is $1$ that is exactly my answer. So, what is wrong?

Comment: the answer $12/32$ is equal to $1 - P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup B)^c$ and according to Morgan's Laws that is equal to $P(A^c \cap B^c)$ but that is the intersection, different of that statement ask, that is $P(A^c \cup B^c)$. So....??

Comment: @EduardoS.  How are you defining events $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $P(A)= P(F=3), P(B) = P(F=2)$

Comment: In that case, notice that what I did is define $\Pr(E \neq 3) = \Pr(A^C)$ and $\Pr(E \neq 2) = \Pr(B^C)$.